# Is this scene using symbolism?

Tags: shuffle

In the 21st episode of the anime *SHUFFLE!*, Kaede tells Asa her feeling towards Rin-kun, the male protagonist, and then cries in Asa's shoulders. The scene is as in the picture. [image]

I think it might use the symbolism from the novel, *Red Rose, White Rose*, by Eileen Chang, considering the following information:

1. The white rose in the novel is a supportive housewife for the male protagonist, Tong. She does all the household chores for Tong, yet Tong doesn't feel a passional love for her, which is similar to Kaede's situation.
2. The red rose in the novel is a passional lover for Tong. She is not his legal wife, yet he enjoys being with her more than his wife. Asa hasn't done as much for Rin-kun as Kaede, yet Rin-kun loves her more than other girls.
3. Even the positions correspond. Kaede is kneeling down to Asa's arms crying, she's the weaker of the two. The white roses are on the lower left of the red roses, overwhelmed by the red roses.

What do you think of this thought? Do you think it right? Does the producer ever say anything about the design of this scene?

Comment: I don't think it's a white rose.  It looks more like a plant with bunches of small flowers, like a lilac.

Comment: @Mary Maybe, but what flowers look like depends on your point of view. This picture(in the link below) provides various points of view, some of which bear certain similarities with the ones in the anime. (https://www.floraqueen.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/shutterstock_1566087013.jpg)

Comment: Animation fidelity aside, there are likely red rose buds and white lilacs. in the language of flowers white lilac can mean (youthful) innocence. Red rose buds can mean alot of things from youthful love to chastity. Production notes on the scene is one thing, but soliciting opinions on this particular scene is subject to speculation.